# checkbox import problems

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, import

Right now I have a custom data set set up that has 3 custom fields inside of it. Inside each custom field is a list of options that can be checked. (checkbox is the option)

In my spreadsheet that I import I have the correct columns and appropriate values in for the options I need to be checked for each contact.

So lets say here are my 3 custom fields with 3 different options (example):
Custom field A contains blue, red, and white in that exact order on the spreadsheet. Custom field B contains purple, orange, yellow in that order on the spreadsheet. Custom field C contains cow, cat, dog in that order on the spreadsheet.

If Example Contact 1 has blue marked, purple marked, and cow marked it will check those off appropriately.

If Example contact 2 has blue marked, yellow marked, and cat marked only blue will import.

I did multiple tests and have come to the conclusion that only the first value of each custom field will import if it is marked. Anything else marked will not be imported.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: how does the data look in your import? ie is blue in one column and red in another, or is it in one cell with commas ie blue,red. I would expect the latter to work, and the former to fail. if that is the case i will reset this as answer

Comment: blue in one column, red in another, and so on. So if I separate by commas in one column rather than a different column per item it should work? If that is true, will it check the appropriate things? Does it have to be in a specific order?

Comment: I tested it with commas in one cell and it worked, thank you for that suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data for importing options needs to be in a single cell. So if your field is COLOUR, then you need a single column for that data in your import file, and you need data such as

- red,blue,orange
- red,orange
- etc

If you need to concatenate your data you may end up with examples like below, but they should also import fine

- red,blue,orange
- red,,orange
- ,blue,orange
- ,,orange
- red,,